# Using regex to place dashes at specific indexes of a string containing numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, regex

So the formatted code needs looks like this:

```
"US-XXX-12-12345"
```

So that's two letters, followed by 3 letters/numbers, followed by 2 numbers, then followed by 5 letters/numbers.
I was able to get it to work using only numbers with the following:

```
return testString
  .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1-$2')
  .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1-$2')
  .replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2')
  .replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2')
```

This returns:

```
"12-345-67-89012"
```

I tried switching the lowercase d's for uppercase ones (representing letters) and it adds all sorts of extra dashes and does not let me backspace. Any and all help is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Ended up solving it like this:

```
const clean = new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/, 'gi')

return testString
    .replace(clean, '')
    .replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9])/, '$1-$2')
    .replace(/(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z0-9])/, '$1-$2')
    .replace(/(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})(-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9])/, '$1$2-$3')
```

Thanks to all who tried to help, I really appreciate it <3

Comment: Can you give input and the expected output?

Comment: Input: "USXXX1212345" -> Output: "US-XXX-12-12345." It's in a react form, so it should happen as you type it in.

Comment: definitely include that information in your question, this is a difficult but solved problem. I would suggest simply using a pre-build package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input

Comment: @Undo personally I'd probably use the package react-input-mask for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask

Comment: Not quite, that is for phone numbers, which are obviously all numbers...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function like this:

```js
function mask(string, model){
    let i = 0;
    return model.replace(/#/g, () => string[i++] || "");
}
```

use:

```
mask("USXXX1212345", "##-###-##-#####") => 'US-XXX-12-12345'
```

the first parameter of the function is the string you want to format, and the next parameter is how it will be formatted

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you asked for but regex probably isn't the best solution to this question.  A better option would probably be to use something like [`react-input-mask`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask) because you mentioned using this in real time in a React form.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";

const Example = () => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

  return (
    <InputMask
      mask="aa-***-99-*****"
      value={inputText}
      onChange={(e) => setInputText(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
};
```

And here's a CodeSandbox example because I can't for the life of my embed a functional example in a SO answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-mask-example-554lcn?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

If the string is known to have the correct pattern, you can replace matches of the following regular expression with a hyphen.

```
(?<=^.{2})|(?<=^.{5})|(?<=^.{7})
```

If lowercase letters are permitted the case-indifferent flag (`i`) needs to be set.

This expression contains an *alternation* comprised of three *positive lookbehind* expressions. It reads, "match the position following the second, fifth or (`|`) seventh  character of the string. Think of `(?<=^.{2})` as matching the location *between* the second and third character of the string. Because it does not match any characters it is referred to as a *zero-width* match.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OrDnu6/1)

---

If the string is *not* known to have the correct pattern, I suggest the string be first matched against the following regular expression to confirm its pattern is correct.

```
 ^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z\d]{3}\d{2}[A-Z\d]{5}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vLuuvw/1)

This regular expression (with the case-indifferent flag is set) can be broken down as follows.

```
^           # match the beginning of the string
[A-Z]{2}    # match two letters
[A-Z\d]{3}  # match three letters or digits
\d{2}       # match two digits
[A-Z\d]{5}  # match five letters or digits
$           # match end of string
```

The first regular expression can be modified to also confirm that the string has the correct pattern but it complicates the expression considerably. If you would like to see that please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that does what you want and works on partial input.

It tolerates strings where the dashes are already in the right spot.

Invalid input is left as is.

```js
const rx = /^(?:(\d{1,2})(?:-?([A-Za-z]{1,3})(?:-?(\d{1,2})(?:-?(\d{1,5}))?)?)?)?/

function addDashes(x) {
  return x.replace(rx, function(...args) {
    const captures = args.slice(1, 5) // get rid of the cruft
    return captures.filter(x => x !== undefined).join("-")
  })
}


const test = (x) => console.log(x, addDashes(x))

test("")
test("invalid123")
test("1")
test("12a")
test("12-a")
test("12abc")
test("12-abc")
test("12abc12")
test("12-abc12")
test("12-abc-12")
test("12abc1254")
test("12-abc1254")
test("12abc-1254")
test("12-abc-1254")
test("12abc12543")
test("12-abc12-543")
test("12abc1254321")
```

The RegExp itself is a bit complex, if you want to see how I built it you can have a look at this [flems sandbox](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgZglgNgpgziAXAbVAOwIYFsZJAOgAsAXLKEAGhAGMB7NYmBvEAXwvW10QICsEqdBk2J4IWAA60ATsQAEwODACOAVybUYFOVgwBPAEYxWcsNNpY5AHRoWpSgLTSYAcxgAPCTatofQuPLS7nIAvHJKahowABQ+cnIA9AB6CRRxOvpGsWjx8QmxVgAmwACMFABMrACUqenxuoYxdbkJDgD8tTm5edHIAIIOAFoYDgBeALqlFADM1Z3d9ZlNXQuJ7fOriQXFZZU1aSsLDVnNq60dB5st21MArHOXm1Xdp3JVze9dn5-+tLD4UFoLmiQU+PjAqjQ1GIEHocgwhUKABEMHBCPBou5nsB0s5iKppDl3PhnBIoBhNCD3NoIVCYfRovgmRhpC44Njmv55NQMBJ8c44KF4ay4Pg4FAIJSynJbs8Egk5G5AhBCnJaGA5MR0XJqNJVGBiM08QScjy+QT4PhIFBGNJMaEAHxyYIAQhCYUhhRgkDQMEKVXwvFoEDQsRADhsn3i1R8rB8fnoAU18HkYUxzxCTt+-0BwOp8MRKLRGKxYOEATDkZ8jArNhDADcMBLCiVytMq+XiGGSh2a12bK2ML2U93yg4hyBPn3RxgDNRh7WQK3x3OF-2l+VZ9RW2vRyvt+VdwOx1uHDvJ9WR8et63bgAWI8b-e3h8Xzszudn8r3x-L08v39NznF92zfadj2fMd71Aqcrw3G9vzvaZyh7N9KBAJRYGhWE0AQHhv0QAAGNgOBATAcDwfBqDgARbGEZgeDYcZWCAA), where you can tweak it to your liking.